# What is a hash table that doesn't know the keys?

Tags: dictionary, hashtable

For example, if I create a dictionary in python I can use `d.keys()` to retrieve the keys.

What is a hash table/dictionary *without* this kind of access? Storage might be an issue and the keys may be of least importance.

Edit (clarification): I want a data structure that can access values through the key but doesn't know the key, only the hash. For example:

```
Hash                                                             Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae|hey!
c9fc5d06292274fd98bcb57882657bf71de1eda4df902c519d915fc585b10190|hello!
```

If I try and access the data structure with the key "this is a key", it will hash that and get "hello!". If I try to access it with the key "foo", I will get "hey!".

We cannot retrieve the keys from this hash table, but we can access the data. This would be useful in cases where storage is important.

Normally, this would be the table:

```
Hash                                                             Value  Key
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae|hey!  |foo
c9fc5d06292274fd98bcb57882657bf71de1eda4df902c519d915fc585b10190|hello!|this is a key
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A hash table with only keys is a Set, but you seem to be asking for one with only values? Or do you mean a thing that stores key/value pairs but you somehow can't get a list of keys? Could you provide some pseudo-code demonstrating what you're looking for? Also, could you explain why you're looking for such a data structure?

Comment: Why do you think what you're asking about is even a thing? There are various ways to get something vaguely like what you're asking about, but it's sort of like asking what's a car without wheels. You have to majorly redesign it for the result to make any sense, and by the time you're done, it's not really a "hash table that doesn't know the keys" any more than a boat is a car without wheels.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) - in this case the value is the key, and implementations generally use the hashcode and equality operations on the items before adding them to the set.

Some implementations of `Set` can be sorted, generally those are referred to as `SortedSet`. Think of `Set<T>` as an equivalent to `Dictionary<T,T>` (and `SortedSet<T>` being approximate of `SortedDictionary<T,T>` in C# parlance.

Sorted variants are generally implemented using binary trees, whereas unsorted implementations use hashing tables. As the key is the value, most implementations only store the value itself.

Which platform / language are you using? Java?

Comment: That's much closer to "hash table without values" than "hash table that doesn't know the keys". Personally, the first thing that came to mind for me is a bloom filter, but while that fits "doesn't know the keys", it's not strictly a hash table.

Comment: I want to be able to access the elements by key, the data structure simply doesn't know the keys -- it has its hash. This is also a theoretical question.

Comment: Theoretically you cannot do this without supplying a function that does value => key conversion, as hashing functions can have collisions. So "foo" and "this is a key" could have the same hash value. In this case, you need to store hash=>values[], and when you find a hash, extract the key from the value and perform the equality comparison.

Comment: @CrazyPython: It has to store enough information to be able to recognize the key, and in general, there's no more efficient way to do that than by storing the key.

Comment: @FlorianDoyon Workarounds can be created, for example secondary hash functions for values that have been detected as duplicated upon addition to the hash table.

Comment: @CrazyPython: How could you detect a collision if you didn't store the key?

Comment: @user2357112 This is called in real life a "bloom filter" or a hash set.

Comment: @CrazyPython: No, bloom filters work entirely differently from the mechanism you propose. Also, I already mentioned those.

Comment: @user2357112 I mean it can recognize the keys, but it doesn't "know" them.

Comment: @CrazyPython: Bloom filters have a significant false positive rate and can't detect collisions.

Comment: @user2357112 True, but my question never required a low false positive rate - plus if you know that you will only be querying existing keys, it doesn't matter. Adding more hash functions can prevent collisions.

Comment: "if you know that you will only be querying existing keys" - if you know that, a bloom filter is useless to you. A bloom filter only lets you tell whether a key is probably present or definitely absent; it doesn't let you associate values with keys. If you know the key is definitely present, a bloom filter tells you nothing.